# How do I sort an STL list object using list::sort() while passing my custom sorting function as a parameter to list::sort?

Tags: c++, list, sorting, stl

Here is the strategy and library call I am referring to:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/

And here is my code excerpts (note that objFromList.getPriority() returns an integer value):

header:

```
class JobTable
{
    private:
        list <ProcessControlBlock> jobTable;
        list<ProcessControlBlock>::iterator iter;

    public:
        JobTable();
        void addProcessControlBlock(int, int, int, int, int);

        void sortJobTableByPriority();
        void printJobTable();
        bool comparePriority( ProcessControlBlock&,
                             ProcessControlBlock&);
};
```

implementation:

```
void JobTable::addProcessControlBlock(int jobNumber, int jobSize, 
                                     int currentTime, int jobPriority, 
                                     int maximumCpuTime)
{
    jobTable.push_back(*(new ProcessControlBlock(jobNumber,jobSize,
                      currentTime, jobPriority,maximumCpuTime)));
}

void JobTable::sortJobTableByPriority()
{
    jobTable.sort(comparePriority);
}

bool JobTable::comparePriority( ProcessControlBlock& first,  
                              ProcessControlBlock& second)
{
    bool isLessThan = false;

    if(first.getJobPriority() < second.getJobPriority())
    {
        isLessThan = true;
    }

    return isLessThan;
}
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    JobTable jobTable;

    jobTable.addProcessControlBlock(6,6,6,6,6);
    jobTable.addProcessControlBlock(2,2,2,2,2);
    jobTable.addProcessControlBlock(1,1,1,1,1);
    jobTable.addProcessControlBlock(4,4,4,4,4);
    jobTable.addProcessControlBlock(5,5,5,5,5);
    jobTable.addProcessControlBlock(3,3,3,3,3);

    jobTable.printJobTable();

    cout << "sorting table..." << endl;
    jobTable.sortJobTableByPriority();

    jobTable.printJobTable();

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the compiler error:

no matching function for call to:

```
std::list<ProcessControlBlock>::sort(<unresolved overloaded function type>)
```

The pointy brackets mean  these guys'<>', for some reason it wouldn't print onto the web page.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it needs to be a free function, or declare it static `static bool comparePriority( const ProcessControlBlock&, const ProcessControlBlock&);`. The alternative is to wrap it inside a struct so it could be used as a functor (as described in the link posted in the comment.)

Because your code has numerous other compile errors, I'm finding it difficult to write up an example for you.

```
bool comparePriority( const ProcessControlBlock& first,  
                              const ProcessControlBlock& second)
{
    bool isLessThan = false;

    if(first.getJobPriority() < second.getJobPriority())
    {
        isLessThan = true;
    }

    return isLessThan;
}

void JobTable::sortJobTableByPriority()
{
    jobTable.sort(comparePriority);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, look at the second overload of list::sort in the given link at the top of your post.
 It says,

```
template <class Compare> void sort (Compare comp);
```

which means it takes an object of some type (named Compare, in this case) as argument.

**It is important that the type should be able to act as comparator.**

So you need to make JobTable::comparePriority as a class first.
And it should implement an binary predicate which has the form:

```
bool operator()(const ProcessControlBlock& first,  const ProcessControlBlock& second) const { 
    // your logic  
    return true; 
}
```

And then, you should pass an instance of this class as parameter of list::sort(), like

> yourList.sort(Compare());

It will produce compile error if you write like below, because parameter should be an object, not type.

```
yourLIst.sort(Compare);
```